# Why is the maximum string literal length in Java 65534?

Tags: java, javac

I compiled this code.　(use `javac 21.0.1`)

```java
public static final String MAX = "AAAAA ...";
```

If I repeat 'A' 65534 times in a literal, the compilation is OK.
**But if I repeat 'A' 65535 times in a literal, I get a compile error 'constant string too long'.**

Why is the length limit 65534 instead of 65535?

## Specification

> CONSTANT_Utf8_info {
> u1 tag;
> u2 length;
> u1 bytes[length];
> }
>
> `length`: The value of the length item gives the number of bytes in the bytes array (not the length of the resulting string).
>
> [Chapter 4. The class File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7)

The maximum length of u2 is 0xFFFF = 65535, not 65534.
In UTF-8, "A" is 1 byte, so isn't the string length limited to 65535?

## Javac source code

[jdk/langtools/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/Gen.java · openjdk/jdk](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/f57b87e8f6b8ca9e3c1e640dca51c2a18ee1ef6a/langtools/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/Gen.java#L530-L538)

```java
private void checkStringConstant(DiagnosticPosition pos, Object constValue) {
    if (nerrs != 0 || // only complain about a long string once
        constValue == null ||
        !(constValue instanceof String str) ||
        str.length() < PoolWriter.MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
        return;
    log.error(pos, Errors.LimitString);
    nerrs++;
}
```

Is the correct code `str.length() <= PoolWriter.MAX_STRING_LENGTH` ?

Comment: probably it would be better to ask the developers of that code, here you'll probably only get some guesses, or maybe some reference to some explanation. It could be to allow an index/pointer to the byte after the last valid one; or to allow an eventual additional zero-byte (historically based on C strings); or just the *old* Off-by-one error  ....

Comment: I was curious what the Eclipse compiler does, since that's based on the same spec, but is a totally unique implementation. If Eclipse failed on 65536, that would be decent support for the argument that javac is wrong. In fact, Eclipse allows longer string literals longer than even 65535, but it will chop them up under the hood into multiple constants, concatenated at runtime.

Comment: @Michael I tested with Eclipse Version 2023-09 (4.29.0). The result was a compilation error: "The type generates a string that requires more than 65535 bytes to encode in Utf8 format in the constant pool"

Comment: @YujiSoftware Ah, I got that too after retrying with something different. It seems like Eclipse can only pull that chopping trick in certain safe situations. If the literal is used directly within a method, it can do it. If the literal is an initializer for a `final` field, it can't.

Comment: @YujiSoftware In that case, then, both Eclipse and javac are consistent, which makes me think they use that 1 byte for something.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I understood. It seems to do it inside the static initializer if there is no "final". The eclipse compiler is smart. It may be the \0 at the end, but it's not necessary as part of the JVM specification, so it's a mystery.

Comment: I'm guessing it is an off by one bug.

Answer (score 2):

The comparison has been in there since [at least 2007](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/f57b87e8f6b8ca9e3c1e640dca51c2a18ee1ef6a/langtools/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/Gen.java#L530). So it may be a bug that no one reported because no one used a string literal that big. I'm guessing the question is just about curiosity because I don't think anyone really needs that extra byte.

Comment: Link fixed. Now it points to the original GitHub commit.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the correct code `str.length() <= PoolWriter.MAX_STRING_LENGTH` ?

No, whether you use `<` or `<=` here makes no difference for the correctness of this check.

The [cited format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7) and its limitation apply to the number of *encoded bytes* in the [modified UTF-8 format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8), not the length of the actual (UTF-16) string.

The number of bytes happen to be equal to the string length if you use only ASCII characters (excluding NUL), like your `A`s. But when you replace the 65534th `A` with, e.g. an `Ä`, it will still pass the “maximum string length” check and create a constant pool entry with 65535 bytes.

Now, if you replace another `A` with `Ä`, it will still pass the string length check but a new error will appear:

```
error: UTF8 representation for string "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA..." is too long for the constant pool
```

which demonstrates that a check for “the real thing” is in place, which makes the preceding string length check entirely obsolete.

Comment: This message is defined: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/cc4b0d9217ed27a9555dc82f0a4247bf9b703f2b/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/resources/compiler.properties#L869-L870
 Used: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/cc4b0d9217ed27a9555dc82f0a4247bf9b703f2b/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/main/JavaCompiler.java#L775

Comment: Throw ClassWriter.StringOverflow: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/cc4b0d9217ed27a9555dc82f0a4247bf9b703f2b/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/PoolWriter.java#L260
 Cause: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/cc4b0d9217ed27a9555dc82f0a4247bf9b703f2b/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/jvm/PoolWriter.java#L387-L390